# How can I validate with Nesjs a DTO as number and not empty?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator

I'm trying to validate a request using DTO.
I need to validate if value is a number and not empty.

When I try to use only the decorator IsNumber() and pass a body with a empty property, validation fails. So, I tried to include the decorator IsNotEmpty() too, but this is not working apparently, because if I pass a empty property, the flow follows. My code is something like this:

```
export class CreateOrderShippingDto implements CreateOrderShippingDtoInterface {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  readonly orderId: number;
}
```

Someone can help?

Comment: maybe some of these `import { Type,Transform } from 'class-transformer';` can help your case

Answer (score 1):

`IsNotEmpty` is a validator for string. From the doc:

> Checks if given value is not empty (!== '', !== null, !== undefined).

Use `IsDefined` instead to check if the value is set:

```
export class CreateOrderShippingDto implements CreateOrderShippingDtoInterface {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: Number,
  })
  @IsDefined()
  @IsNumber()
  readonly orderId: number;
}
```

As a side note, `IsDefined` ignores the `skipMissingProperties` property from the configuration so this is a safe way to enforce a value to be set.